# How to use variable in cts:search?

Tags: xquery, marklogic-10

How to use variable in cts:search as first param.

```
let $doc-type := 'Employee'
let $query := some cts query
return
    cts:search($doc-type,$query)
```

Comment: Is your intent for `$doc-type`  to be the name of a collection or a path expression (in this example for `/Employee` or `//Employee`)?

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter is an expression, typically an XPath but can also be a reference to a collection or `fn:doc()`.

If your intent was to search for documents in the `Employee` collection, then you could use this:

```
let $doc-type := 'Employee'
let $query := cts:true-query()
return
    cts:search(collection($doc-type), $query)
```

If your intent was to provide a dynamic XPath expression from a string to apply to that first param as a path expression, that is not as easy.

You may need to generate a stringified search expression with that path expression and then use [`xdmp:eval()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval):

```
let $doc-type := '/Employee'
let $query := cts:true-query()
return
  xdmp:eval("cts:search("||$doc-type||", "||$query||")")
```

[Using `xdmp:eval()` is generally not advised](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/first-class-functions/), due to security and performance concerns.

If you were looking for documents that have `Employee` as the root element of the document (`/Employee`), then you could use one of the [new (in MarkLogic 11) cts document query functions](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/guide/release-notes/en/new-features-in-marklogic-11/new-cts-document-queries.html) [`cts:document-root-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:document-root-query) and apply it to the query instead of as a path expression:

```
let $doc-type := 'Employee'
let $query := cts:true-query()
return
    cts:search(doc(), cts:and-query(( cts:document-root-query(xs:QName($doc-type)), $query)) )
```